# How can I transition a gradient using css3?

Tags: css, css-transitions

I didn't see anything that really hit on what I'm trying to do. I know that animating gradients used to not be possibly but I think that's changed in the last year or so. Does anyone have any advice about how to move four divs with different background gradients through css3 transitions? I'm trying to create a nighttime to dawn to day gradient transition and can't seem to make it work. Ideally I'd love to do it just with css3 but if I have to use JavaScript or jQuery, that's fine. Also, I'd like to make it happen on load and not need a :hover pseudo class.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  If you post the code you tried and what specifically is wrong with it, you'll usually get good help.  Generic "show me how to code this" questions tend to just get downvoted.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I was asked to write a transition gradient using css3 and I'm just not sure how to do it. Below is a link to what I was working with. I can easily achieve some effect with hover but I'm leaning towards using a JavaScript function to move through the transitions unless someone has a suggestion or a push in the right direction.

http://cdpn.io/acmlC